# Date parameters validation using Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express, joi

I would validate a timestamp passed through query string. This is the routing code:

**routing:**

```
router.route('/:userId/:orchardId/:sTime/:eTime')
  .get(authorize(LOGGED_USER), validate(getByInterval), controller.getByInterval);
```

I would validate the eTime parameter to have max value the actual timestamp

**validation schema:**

```
getByInterval: {
    params: {
      userId: Joi.string().regex(/^[0-9]+$/, 'numbers').required(),
      orchardId: Joi.string().regex(/^[0-9]+$/, 'numbers').required(),
      sTime: Joi.date().timestamp().required(),
      eTime: Joi.date().timestamp('unix').max(moment().unix() * 1000),
    }
```

**test:**

```
it('should get 200 when data are found', async () => {
      const userId = 1;
      const orchardId = 1;
      const sTime = (moment().unix() * 1000) - 3000;
      const eTime = moment().unix() * 1000;
      return request(app)
        .get(`/v1/data/${userId}/${orchardId}/${sTime}/${eTime}`)
        .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${userAccessToken}`)
        .expect(httpStatus.OK)
    });
```

I tried in many ways but no one works... I receive this error:

**error:**

```
{"code":400,"message":"Validation error","errors":[{"field":"eTime","location":"params","messages":["\"eTime\" must be less than or equal to \"Thu Oct 12 2017 09:49:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)\""],"types":["date.max"]}]}
```

Comment: Why are you converting the timestamp to milliseconds when you've set Joi to expect seconds? i.e. `timestamp('unix')`. If you want to work with milliseconds use `'javascript'` as the Joi datetime type

Comment: sorry I don't get it...could you write me the right validation?